# How to use Flow retry function on a specific event?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I see that Flow has a [retry](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/retry.html) mechanism, but my use case is somehow different from what I see in the doc, I have a fragment containing a list that fills from API when opening this fragment, but the API calls may be failed and throw an exception for any reason, in this case, I want to show a button that calls the API again on clicking, as follows:

Repository

```
fun getData(): Flow<Result<T>> = service.getData()
```

ViewModel

```
val data: Flow<Result<T>> = repo.getData()
```

Fragment

```
viewModel.data.collect{ result ->
   if(result is Error){
       showRetryButton() // Show the retry button on failed API
   }
   ....
}

retryButton.setOnClickListener{
   // do something to retry the API call 
}
```

Can Flow *retry* help me here? if not, what do you think is the best way to call the failed API again?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `retry` can help in this case. Basically to fire an API request `repo.getData()` should be called, so just call it and collect returned `Flow`:

```
// Fragment:

private var job: Job? = null // save here the job of collecting data

private fun fetchData() {
    job?.cancel() // cancel previous job
    job = lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.getData().collect {
            if(result is Error) {
                showRetryButton() // Show the retry button on failed API
            }
            //...
        }
    }
}

retryButton.setOnClickListener{
    fetchData()
} 

// ViewModel:

fun getData() = repo.getData()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I think it the better to make the data in VM variable instead of fun because the fun doesn't save the data, while the variable does.

Comment: The function `repo.getData()` should be triggered each time the `retryButton` is pressed, If you can do this using the property then it is ok.